# Anthill to Jenkins Migration

Tags: jenkins, anthill

Could you please let me know how to do AnthillPro projects migration to Jenkins?

Kindly let me know if there any better links on net.

Comment: This question might not attract many answers as written. You should take a look at the the [ask] guidance. Generally, questions on StackOverflow work best when they're _specific_ to a single development/coding task. This question is pretty broad, and "please find me some links" requests often get no or poor quality answers. Can you focus on a single job, configuration, or concept of Jenkins vs. Anthill?

Answer (score 0):

I found two option for that:
1. The best one - Manually created a Jenkins file that described the best I could of the AHP process
2. Partially, for me it didn't made the job - From the site http://epicforce.net/build-and-release/ download a Jenkins plugin that suppose create the proper Jenkins file

Enjoy